# Asp.Net core 3.1 not binding file to IFormFile property inside model

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, form-data, iformfile

I have an http post request in my controller that takes a model with an IFormFile property:

```
 public ActionResult Post([FromForm] PageModel pageModel)
 {
           // process data
 }
```

The pageModel class:

```
    public class PageModel 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }  
        public string Title { get; set; }  
        public Image ImageModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImageModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public IFormFile Img { get; set; }
        public Guid? PageId { get; set; }
    }
```

when i receive the pageModel all the data are as expected even for the ImageModel properties like the Url and PageId exept for the **Img** IFormFile which is always null.

when i add:

```
var files = Request.Form.Files;
```

inside my post request, **files** contains all the missing **Img** files.

is their a way to bind the files directly to the IFormFile Img property?

**the api request is called from an angular client using FormData.**

```
createPage(pageModel : PageModel): Observable<PageModel> {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', pageModel .title); 

        formData.append('[image][pageId]', pageModel.pageId);
        formData.append('[image][url]', pageModel .image.url);
        formData.append('[image][img]', pageModel .image.img, pageModel.image.img.name);

        return this.http.post<PageModel>(this.Url, formData)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the Angular code?

Comment: Done, i edited the question and added the client code

Comment: Also, there seems to be such error if you are using the `ApiControllerAttribute`. Try removing it first. It's like a bug or something.

Comment: Still not working @bolkay